# How to read input file and store integers into array in C

Tags: c, file-io

I am working on a CPU Scheduler simulator in C and I have an input file with the following:

```
1 0 10
2 0 9
3 3 5
4 7 4
5 10 6
6 10 7
```

I would like to store the numbers in a first, second, and third columns in an array separately in the following manner:

```
a1[0] = 1     a2[0] = 0     a3[0] = 10
a1[1] = 2     a2[1] = 0     a3[1] = 9
a1[2] = 3     a2[2] = 3     a3[2] = 5
a1[3] = 4     a2[3] = 7     a3[3] = 4
a1[4] = 5     a2[4] = 10    a3[4] = 6
a1[5] = 6     a2[5] = 10    a3[5] = 7
```

I am having trouble understanding how to implement this through C implementation. My current code is as follows:

```
int pList[len], wtList[len], btList[len];

char *str[256];
char *token[30];

FILE *input;

input = fopen(argv[1], "r");

if (input == NULL) {
    printf("File not found. \n");
    exit(1);
}

while (fgets(str, sizeof str, input)) {
    if (sscanf(str, "%d %d %d", &pList, &wtList, &btList) == 3) { 
        totalJobs++;
    } else {
        printf("Input text is not in 3 column format. Please check. \n");
    }
}

fclose(input);

//printf("Scheduling algorithm: %s\n", argv[2]);
//printf("Total %d tasks are read from \"%s\". press 'enter' to start...\n", totalJobs, input);
//printf("==================================================================\n");
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    printf(pList[i]);
    printf(wtList[i]);
    printf(btList[i]);
}
```

Ideally I would want an abstract implementation of putting these numbers into an array because the input file should be able to have more or less rows and still work. I apologize if my formatting is off as I am new with using Stack Overflow. Thanks in advance for the help and please let me know if my question is still unclear.

UPDATE 1: I did the following corrections as stated and I am now getting a `Segmentation fault (Core dumped)` error. Could it be because I did not have a `*` in front of the arrays?

Comment: @Fredrik Considering p, at, and bt are the arrays, do I need to do anything in distributing them correctly or does sscanf automatically fill the arrays with the integers it reads?

Comment: Like this: `if (sscanf(str, "%d %d %d", &p[totalJobs], &at[totalJobs], &bt[totalJobs]) == 3)`

Comment: Have you learned about structures yet?  It looks as though you'd do better with an array of structures rather than three parallel arrays.  You should check to ensure that you don't overflow your arrays, whether there's one array of structures or three parallel arrays of numbers.

Comment: Structures are particularly useful if you need to sort the data based on one particular member.

Comment: Re the edit: change `char *str[256];` to `char str[256];`

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it! I'll include the updates on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It would be more useful to future readers if you don't modify the faulty code in the question. Otherwise there's no question. You can post the solution as an answer, but newcomers often thing they should be modifying the code they posted. SO isn't really a step-by-step code correction service.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many problems.

1) Your arrays aren't initialized, which is a sure-fire way of getting unreadable output and potentially very bad bugs.

2) Several of the variables in your code aren't declared. In the future, please post the code EXACTLY as it is for you, so that it is immediately compilable. A tried and true way of not getting any answers to your questions is to post code that needs to be substantially edited before it even compiles: people generally just go "screw this, not worth it" and you really can't blame them.

3) Your way of reading files is inefficient both in terms of performance wise code structure. The best way of reading files is to read them in one go, and then parse them to get what you need out of them.

4) Your printfs in the last for-loop are completely wrong, which is strange because in the commented out printfs above as well as sscanf you seem to understand how format string work. I think this is an error of not reading your code VERY carefully. Please do that from now on.

Here's a complete program that I think does roughly what you require:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    #define jobArrayLength (6ULL)
    #define stringLength   (256ULL)
    int  pList[jobArrayLength] = {0}, wtList[jobArrayLength] = {0}, btList[jobArrayLength] = {0};
    int  totalJobs = 0; // Used to not be declared
    char str[stringLength] = {0} ; // Used to be uninitialized

    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 
    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("File not found. \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fread(str, 1, stringLength, input); // Used to be sizeof str which is wrong
    fclose(input);
    int i; // Used to not be declared
    int stringIndex = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < jobArrayLength; i++) {
        if (sscanf(str + stringIndex, "%d %d %d", pList + i, wtList + i, btList + i) == 3) { // used to not index into the array
            totalJobs++;
            while (str[stringIndex++] != '\n' && stringIndex != stringLength) {} // Skip to next row of numbers
        } else {
            printf("Input text is not in 3 column format. Please check. \n");
        }
    }

    //printf("Scheduling algorithm: %s\n", argv[2]);
    //printf("Total %d tasks are read from \"%s\". press 'enter' to start...\n", totalJobs, input);
    //printf("==================================================================\n");
    for (i = 0; i < jobArrayLength; i++) {
        printf("%d, %d, %d\n", pList[i], wtList[i], btList[i]); // Used to just print an int array element, which is not how printf works.
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```